# Vertical space before and after equations

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

The vertical space before and after equation (1) is greater than the vertical space before and after equation (2).

Which is the rule/reason for that?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\doublespacing
Is it normal that the vertical space before and after this equation:
\begin{equation}
a = b + c
\end{equation}
is more than the space before and after this other equation?
\begin{equation}
d=\sum_{i=1}^{k}e_i
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is normal. Measure the distance between the baselines.

Comment: The spaces are exactly the same -- compare the gaps between the surrounding text, not the distance from the highest/lowest elements of the displayed material.  The difference you observe is the fact that there is a large operator with limits in the second display; that is not part of the defined measurement, which is correctly described by @egreg.

Comment: use \vspace before and after the equation like \vspace{-.5cm}

Comment: @Jarod_83 -- This is almost never a good idea. Using an explicit `\vspace`, even negative, before a display makes it possible for the page to break there, a condition that is ordinarily prohibited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spaces are exactly the same -- compare the gaps between the surrounding text, not the distance from the highest/lowest elements of the displayed material.

The difference you observe is the fact that there is a large operator with limits in the second display; that is not part of the defined measurement, which is correctly described by @egreg (in a comment) as the distance between baselines.